# Image not moving for the life of me

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
# Some colors
GREEN = ( 0,255,0)
BLUE = ( 0, 0, 255)
WHITE = ( 255, 255, 255)
BLACK = ( 0, 0, 0)
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#Screen
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode([1000,700])
#Title
pygame.display.set_caption("Trying to move things")

#Variables
x_position = 100
y_position = 100
x_speed = 0
y_speed = 0
#Positions
image_image_positions = [x_position,y_position]


#Graphics
image_image = pygame.image.load("izzat.png").convert()
image_image.set_colorkey(BLACK)


#Main loop ____
done = False

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    # Keyboard commands.

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_speed = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_speed = 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                x_speed = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                x_speed = 5
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_speed = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_speed = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                x_speed += 0
    if y_position + y_speed >=0 and y_position + y_speed + 60 <=500:
        y_position += y_speed
    x_position += x_speed


    SCREEN.fill(GREEN)
    SCREEN.blit(image_image, image_image_positions)
    print(x_position)
    print(y_position)


    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)


pygame.quit()
```

Hello, I have been having a problem which I'm really not happy at because I have been trying to fix it for a while now. So basically I have a image, and I wish to move the image based on the keyboard inputs, yet whatever I try nothing works. I then wondered maybe the y and x position aren't changing at all which is why the images positions are not changing, well I did print( those positions) but it the positions are definitely changing, the variables, so I do not get how the image positions do not change at all. Then I thought maybe because it's a tuple, so I changed it to parenthesis, that also did not work. I just don't get why my image position doesn't move if the variables for the position of the image do change. Thank you if you could help me in any way. I have looked this up but I couldn't find any help. Thank you for your help if you help me!

Update__________
Ok so apparently the image_image_position stays the same despite the variables changing when I printed the positions of image_image_position. Is there any way to change them and not have them stay at 100,100 all the time and change with the variables being changed?

Comment: Hint: If you change `x_position` does that change the value held in `image_image_positions`?

Comment: It does not? I just printed those positions and they don't change. Huh, thank you for finding the problem but how do I change the value then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't assigned the speeds.

image_image_positions[0] = xspeed
image_image_positions[1] = yspeed

Comment: It didn't work? Do I have to put this after or before the loop. Also i'm trying to make the positions x and y affect the tuple not the speeds. Thank you for your response anyways.. I also tried replacing xspeed and y speed in your answers with y_position and x_position but that didn't make the image_image_positions change either.

Answer (score 1):

You are only changing your variables `yspeed` and `xspeed`, but you are not setting the actual positions of the image. Add the following line before the `blit`:

```
image_image_positions = [x_position,y_position]
```

Full code:

```
import pygame
# Some colors
GREEN = ( 0,255,0)
BLUE = ( 0, 0, 255)
WHITE = ( 255, 255, 255)
BLACK = ( 0, 0, 0)
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#Screen
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode([1000,700])
#Title
pygame.display.set_caption("Trying to move things")

#Variables
x_position = 100
y_position = 100
x_speed = 0
y_speed = 0
#Positions
image_image_positions = [x_position,y_position]


#Graphics
image_image = pygame.image.load("izzat.png").convert()
image_image.set_colorkey(BLACK)


#Main loop ____
done = False

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    # Keyboard commands.

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_speed = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_speed = 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                x_speed = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                x_speed = 5
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_speed = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_speed = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                x_speed += 0
    if y_position + y_speed >=0 and y_position + y_speed + 60 <=500:
        y_position += y_speed

    x_position += x_speed

    image_image_positions = [x_position,y_position]
    SCREEN.fill(GREEN)
    SCREEN.blit(image_image, image_image_positions)
    print(x_position)
    print(y_position)


    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)


pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

While you ARE updating the x/y positions, this isn't changing where the image is being drawn:

```
    SCREEN.blit(image_image, image_image_positions)
```

image_image_positions, is never changed throughout the life-span of your application (besides startup).

To fix this simply add the update into your loop:

```
image_image_positions = [x_position,y_position]
```